# Why JPEG scan data uses bit length prefixes if Huffman Coding have so called "prefix property"?

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code

If Huffman code is a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) why JPEG's DC and AC coefficients are encoded as pairs of [length][bits]? Why we need length prefix at all?

And why we encode lengths of values and not values themselves (correct me if I'm wrong)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've got long runs of zero entries. You'd need a bit zero to encode the zeroes. Then you'd get runs of zeros, which is undesireable for electrical engineering reasons - it can cause a sender and receiver to go out of synchronisation if you send longs tuns of the same bit, and runs are also used for signal synchronisation in MPEG.